# "System.FormatException: 'The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0." in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, formatexception

How to solve this error

> "System.FormatException: 'The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0."

Every time I press the data in the data grid view, that error appears. Because I would have edited the case data, I couldn't edit it because of that error. Im beginner in c#

**Here is my code:**

```
private void editButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE sr_tb SET fullname=@fn,positions=@p,projects=@pr,startofcontract=@scd,endofcontract=@ecd,status=@s,remarks=@r WHERE SRID=@sk", connection);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idn", idnumberTextBox.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fn", fullnameTextBox.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", positionsComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pr", projectsComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scd", startDatePicker.Value.Date);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ecd", endDatePicker.Value.Date);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s", statusComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@r", remarksTextBox.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sk", key);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("SR updated successfully!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        connection.Close();

        SRData();

        Reset();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}

int key = 0;

private void srDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    idnumberTextBox.Text = srDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    fullnameTextBox.Text = srDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    positionsComboBox.Text = srDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    projectsComboBox.Text = srDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    startDatePicker.Text = srDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
    endDatePicker.Text = srDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
    statusComboBox.Text = srDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
    remarksTextBox.Text = srDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value.ToString();

    if (fullnameTextBox.Text == "")
    {
        key = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        key = Convert.ToInt32(srDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Then here in this code I got that error**

`startDatePicker.Text = srDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();`
`endDatePicker.Text = srDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();`

Comment: Can you give an example of a value that causes the error?

Comment: Not one bit of that code directly relates to the error you're getting.

Comment: You're calling `ToString` on a lot of stuff, so you're probably calling it on something that's a `DateTime` value (but the property is declared `object`) so you're adding the parameter as a string in a display-oriented format rather than as a `DateTime` value. Stop calling `ToString` and deal with the *actual* data type by casting. (And don't go using `Convert` methods because that's the same kind of crutch as `ToString`.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
    startDatePicker.Text = srDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
 endDatePicker.Text = srDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
```

Maybe it is null or an empty string
set a breakpoint and look at the values.

You might be better served to do this

```
endDatePicker.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(srDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value);
```